# Angular ng-show (or ng-if) not updating on value change

Tags: ng-show

I have a simple example at [plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Umd5ZnPaPBfxjpokP49v?p=preview). I have an ng-show on one element and a select as another element. The select should toggle showing/hiding the other (input) element. Initially setting the select to Yes shows the other input element as expected. Then setting the select to No does toggle the scope value to false as expected, but does not hide the input element.

I've scoured the other posts related to this and the ones I found are around having or not having {{}} on the ng-show (I don't as it should be) or not having the value on $scope (which I do). I thought is may be a $scope.apply() issue, but then why does the 1st change to Yes work? Also adding the apply still does not make the No(false) work. What am I missing?

TIA!

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', []);

app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope) {
  $scope.conf = {};
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to check **ng-show="conf.is_ieee=='true'"** instead of **ng-show="conf.is_ieee"**. Check this plunker.

```html
<div class="col-md-4" ng-show="conf.is_ieee=='true'">
    <label class="form-label">IEEE Conference ID:</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" name="ieee-id" ng-model="conf.ieee_id"/>
  </div>
```

http://plnkr.co/edit/MXvuhSPB0ChJyDrvPI55?p=preview

Comment: Ahh yes... it's not an expression so that makes perfect sense. Amazing how we can get lost in the code sometimes and miss what's right in front of us!!! THANKS!

Comment: @dinesh-dabhi if it is bind to model it changes.but the question is to use ng-if with scope value change

Comment: conf.is_ieee=='true' doesn't work, rather conf.is_ieee==true works